# Why git clone command isn't working?

Tags: permissions, git, cloning

I'm new to github and was trying out the git clone command,
and when I try to run it , it gives me an error saying

Cloning into 'rugged'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.123' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Thanks :)

Comment: Which command exactly did you use?

Answer (score 0):

An [official article](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) explains a few solutions to the problem, it is a likely issue for a new user to the repository that the [public key](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/#verify-the-public-key-is-attached-to-your-account) is not attached to you account.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.